# Simple webView that is being covered by keyboard

Tags: android, android-webview, android-softkeyboard

I'm having an issue that seems to have been documented but I can't sort out my app. I've read where I need to turn off FullScreen but I don't see it in my project. My goal: trying to get the webView to adjust and allow the keyboard without hiding the rest of my webView when input boxes are under the keyboard. I'm not a seasoned Android developer (clearly). Would love any input.

My Manifest

```
    <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="8" android:minSdkVersion="5"/>

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MOUNT_UNMOUNT_FILESYSTEMS"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <supports-screens android:largeScreens="true" />

    <application 
        android:icon="@drawable/icon" 
        android:label="@string/app_name" 
        android:allowBackup="true">

        <activity 
            android:name="XXXX" 
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Light"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
            android:launchMode="singleTask">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>

        </activity>
        <activity android:name="XXXX"></activity>

    </application>
    </manifest>
```

My Main Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/bottom_menu"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#000000">
        <!-- menu bar -->

        <include
            android:layout_height="36dp"
            layout="@layout/layout_footer_menu" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/bottom_menu"
        android:id="@+id/activity_main"
        android:paddingBottom="0sp" android:background="#000000">

        <WebView
            android:id="@+id/webView"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />

    </LinearLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

In your manifest, change the `windowSoftInputMode` attribute for your Activity. From this:

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustPan"
```

into this

```
   android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

This will resize your widgets so that they fit in the area left. See the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).

Comment: That didn't seem to do anything. I changed it and tested on my device and the webView didn't resize. I have a footer layout. Could that be causing an issue?